# React Router 6 link to element within route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Problem seems very basic, but I cant seem to find an answer even though I've read documentation, googled, and looked at tutorials. I'm trying to link to a certain component on a link. Basically it's a situation of "Read more about our mental Health Coach here (Links to the "about us" page)" <--- This is where I'm trying to link to the last person on our "About Us" page, meaning it should link to `"/aboutus"` and then scroll down to the last person on the page.

I tried the following:

```
<Link
  className="descriptionTextMobile"
  id="hoverLink"
  style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}
  to="/aboutus#najmedin"
>
  Read more about our coach here{" "}
</Link>
```

```
<Link
  className="descriptionTextMobile"
  id="hoverLink"
  style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}
  to="/aboutus"
  onClick={() => {
    const element = document.getElementById("najmedin");
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }}
>
  Read more about our coach here{" "}
</Link>
```

I'm using routing as follows:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/aboutUs" element={<AboutUsScreen />} />
  // Other routes
</Routes>
```

Any idea on what to put in the `Link` to link to `"/aboutus"` and then scroll down to this component?

```
<Container style={{ marginTop: "80px" }} className="desktopView">
  <AbbeDesktop />
  <JockeDesktop />
  <MartinDesktop />
  <NajDesktop id="najmedin" />  <----------------------
</Container>
```

Also I'm using this `useEffect` to reset scroll on every page, but to not use it when there's a URL hash `"#"` in the route.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.hash === "") {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
}, [location]);
```

It appears that :

```
    if (params.get("scrollToComponent")) {
      refToComponent.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }, [location.search]);
```

Works on desktop. However when i'm in mobile screens something is interfering with the scrolling.

````
      <Container className="mobileView">
        <hr style={{ margin: "0" }} />

        <div>
          {showFullDescriptionAbbe ? <AbbePrez /> : <AbbeShort />}
          {showFullDescriptionAbbe ? (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionAbbe(false)}
            >
              Visa mindre
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionAbbe(true)}
            >
              Läs mer
            </p>
          )}
          {showFullDescriptionJocke ? <JockePrez /> : <JockeShort />}
          {showFullDescriptionJocke ? (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionJocke(false)}
            >
              Visa mindre
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionJocke(true)}
            >
              Läs mer
            </p>
          )}
          {showFullDescriptionMartin ? <MartinPrez /> : <MartinShort />}
          {showFullDescriptionMartin ? (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionMartin(false)}
            >
              Visa mindre
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionMartin(true)}
              id="najmedin"
            >
              Läs mer
            </p>
          )}

          {showFullDescriptionNajmedin ? <NajPrez /> : <NajShort />}
          {showFullDescriptionNajmedin ? (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionNajmedin(false)}
            >
              Visa mindre
            </p>
          ) : (
            <p
              className="visaMer"
              style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
              onClick={() => setShowFullDescriptionNajmedin(true)}
            >
              Läs mer
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </Container>
    ```
````

Comment: Try adding `document.querySelector(location.hash)?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });` in an else branch in the effect.

Comment: You might find [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link) to be a library of interest for your use case.

Comment: Hash link didnt work.

Comment: Hash links appear to work for me with the code you've provided. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-6-link-to-element-within-route-igvw6k) demo.

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique identifier on the element that you want to scroll to. Suppose, it is an h2 element you want to scroll to.

```
<h2 data-id="najmadin"> Najmadin </>
```

Find the top position of the `h2` element, and use `window.scrollTo`  to scroll to it.

```
const scrollToH2 = (hash) => {
  const element = document.querySelector(`h2[data-id='${hash}']`);

  if (element) {
    const { top } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { marginTop } = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    const y = top + window.scrollY - parseInt(marginTop);
    window.scrollTo({ top: y, behavior: "smooth" });
  }
}
```

#### From another page / route

Get the `hash` and scroll to it with delay in `useEffect`.

```
const useScrollToElement = () => {
  const { hash } = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hash && hash.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => scrollToH2(hash.replace("#", "")), 500);
    }
  }, [hash]);
}
```

`useScrollToElement` is a custom hook that can be used in any React component. Use it at the top level.

```
const NajDesktop = () => {
  useScrollToElement();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 data-id="najmadin">Najmadin</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

#### From the same page

If you want to scroll to an element from the same page when you click on an element, just call the `scrollToH2` function in `onClick`.

```
<Link
  className="descriptionTextMobile"
  id="hoverLink"
  style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}
  to="/aboutus"
  onClick={() => scrollToH2("najmadin")}
>
  Read more about our coach here{" "}
</Link>
```